# Nested using statements

Tags: vb.net, using-statement

As Eric Gunnerson shows in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericgu/nested-using-statements) blog post, in C# you can nest `using` statements as:

```c#
using (StreamWriter w1 = File.CreateText("W1"))
using (StreamWriter w2 = File.CreateText("W2"))
{
    // code here
}
```

Is there a similar way to do it in VB.Net? I want to avoid too many indentation levels.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Like this:

```
Using a As New Thingy(), _
      b As New OtherThingy()
        ...
End Using
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can do:

```
Using w1 = File.CreateText("W1"), w2 = File.CreateText("W2")
    ' Code goes here. '
End Using
```